# How to make AdMob insterstitial Ads delay for 1 min?

Tags: android, admob

Lets say people start my application and they click for an activity from `RecyclerView` and it display interstitial ads then the application add gap for 1 min so user cant see ads even if they click for an `Activity` from `RecyclerView`.

When 1 min passed and they click another recycle view item for displaying another activity they can see another Intersials ads

How to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this programmatically, you can simply set a [frequency cap](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6244508) for your interstitial Ad:

> 1. Sign in to your AdMob account at https://apps.admob.com.
> 2. Click Apps in the sidebar.
> 3. Select the name of your app. If you don't see it in the list of recent apps, you can click View all apps to search a list of all of
>      the apps you've added to AdMob.
> 4. Click App settings in the sidebar.
> 5. Click Edit beside Interstitial frequency capping.
> 6. Select an interstitial frequency capping option:
>
>    - No cap on interstitial impressions in this app: Select this option to disable frequency capping for this app.
>    - Enable the following cap per user: Enter the number of impressions you want to allow to appear per user across all
>        interstitial ad units in this app and select a period of time (per
>        minute, per hour, or per day).
> 7. Click Save.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign current time in milliseconds in an ***long*** variable and check difference between User Click Time and the previous time. If difference was bigger than 60*1000 milliseconds show advertisement.

Getting current time in milliseconds:

```
long savedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Needed condition:

```
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - savedTime > 60 * 1000) { // 60,000 ms = 1 min
       //  Show Advertisement
    }
```